# Google Photos API to archive photos

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

From the Google Photos API documentation, I found that we have the filter for the archived File/Album, but I am not able to find any reference to Archive. Are there any ways to archive the Google Photos through the REST API?

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/apply-filters#archived-state

```json
{
  "filters": {
    "includeArchivedMedia": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a definite "no", as it currently stands. See the similar question from 2017 about deleting, here: [Is it possible to delete a photo or an album created via Google Photos API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51260814/is-it-possible-to-delete-a-photo-or-an-album-created-via-google-photos-api)

If you examine the page on Authorization Scopes (here: https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/authorization) you will find that each scope is for reading, editing or sharing. This does include removing media items from albums, and unsharing albums, though even that it limited to those created via the API.